# Query Django models two levels down foreign key relations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a dictionary application using Django. 
The main models in this app are `Expression`s, `Definition`s, and `City`s.
The logic is that each `Expression` has one or more `Definition`s, and each `Definition` is associated with one `City`.

**Here is my problem**: I want to query all the `City`s associated with an `Expression`, from the `Expression` level.

For example, I would like to do `an_expression.cities` and get all the `City`s associated with (each `Definition` of) `an_expression`.

**Here are my models**:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField()

class Expression(models.Model):
    expression = models.CharField()
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City, related_name="expressions")

class Definition(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name="definitions")
    expression = models.ForeignKey(Expression, related_name="definitions")
```

This code now works. However, every time I add a `Definition` I need to add the `City` to both the `Expression` --AND-- the `Definition` itself.

**Here is my question**: Is there a way to only add the `City` to the `Definition`, and then somehow be able to query `an_expression.cities` and get all cities (basically getting rid of the `cities` field in the `Expression` model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use identical `related_name` for different foreign keys in `Definition` class

```
class Definition(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name="definitions_city")
    expression = models.ForeignKey(Expression, related_name="definitions_expression")
```

You can get `city` list for `Expression` like this

```
an_expression = Expression.objects.first()
an_expression.definitions_expression.values('city__city')
```

So no need for `cities` ManyToManyField in `Expression` class